# Problem in creating Excel Files with ruby

Tags: ruby, spreadsheet

I am using Spreadsheet for ruby for creating excel files. Now I want that a excel must be created when it doesnt exist. So I wrote this -:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spreadsheet'
include Spreadsheet

workbook = Spreadsheet.open "data__#{$KEYWORD}.xlsx" rescue Excel.new("data__#{$KEYWORD}.xlsx")
```

But Always keeps throwing this error -

```
undefined method `new' for Spreadsheet::Excel:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you want to use `Spreadsheet::Excel::Workbook.new`. As the error you get points out, `Spreadsheet::Excel` is a module, and not instantiable.

[Check the documentation.](http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/GUIDE_txt.html)